# Android - Updating recycler view is not working well In Listener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have adding list method like this

```
private void addMessage(String username, String message) {
  mMessages.add(msgObj);
  mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mMessages.size()-1);
  Log.d("username", msgObj.getUsername());
  Log.d("message", msgObj.getMessage());
  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  scrollToBottom();
}
```

And I call this in this method

```
private WebSocket connect() throws IOException, WebSocketException
    {
        return new WebSocketFactory()
            .setConnectionTimeout(TIMEOUT)
            .createSocket(SERVER)
            .addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
                // A text message arrived from the server.
                public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String message) {
                    Log.d("WebSocketFactory", message);
                    JSONObject json = null;
                    try {
                        json = new JSONObject(message);
                        if(json.getString("type").equals("msg")) {
                            JSONObject data = json.getJSONObject("data");
                            addMessage(data.getString("author"), data.getString("text"));
                        }
                    } catch(JSONException je) {
                        je.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            })
            .addExtension(WebSocketExtension.PERMESSAGE_DEFLATE)
            .connect();
    }
```

And this method is in async task

```
private class NetworkTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> {
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                try {
                    ws = connect();
                } catch(IOException ioe) {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }

            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }
        }
```

And It does not work well.
Debug log in addMessage method is shown. I can see the log
Log.d("username", msgObj.getUsername());
Log.d("message", msgObj.getMessage());
But, view does not update. but when I scroll the view, view is updated then.
I have to scroll the view every time to see the messages.

BUT! when I call addMessages method in onCreate, this just work very well.

I can't find what is difference..

How can I solve this problem? I have to call the addMessage In onTextMessage Listner

Comment: try updating the adapter in a `UI Thread` implement `UI thread` in the `addMessage()`

Comment: It worked! Thanks so much